# Как поставить ударение?

Tags: фонетика

Договор, договоров, договоры или договора... Как правильно ставить ударение?
Что значит профессионализм, как это понять, вот в деловом стиле общения как надо употреблять эти слова, как ставить ударение при разговоре в деловой форме???

Comment: А можно узнать, зачем аж три вопросительных знака? Это вопрос жизни и смерти?))))

Answer (score 4):

Ольга, в деловом стиле общения ударение надо ставить правильно! Я не могу представить, чтобы в новостях сказали "Руководители государств заключили дОговор". Только договОр! Почему Вы в официальной обстановке должны говорить по-другому? Действительно, произношение "дОговор" очень часто встречается в профессиональной среде. т.е. так часто произносят люди, которые эти договоры заключают. С развитием частного предпринимательства (кто только не заключает договоры!) такое употребление стало ещё более частотным. Но, на мой взгляд, не стало более правильным. Свою лепту внес и небезызвестный Фурсенко. Если посмотрим в он-лайн словари, то увидим разные точки зрения. В последних словарях часто вариант "дОговор" указывается как разговорный (это значит - в неофициальной обстановке), а в некоторых (правда, не в орфоэпических, поэтому их мнение не может быть приоритетным) даже признается вариантом наравне с "договОр".

Я считаю, что  дома вы можете сказать (если уж так привыкли): я дОговор подписала. Но на официальной встрече нужно сказать: давайте обсудим условия договОра.

Answer (score 3):

ДоговОр! Говорите так всегда - не ошибетесь!

Answer (score 2):

ДоговОр, договОров, договОры;

дОговор - считался разговорным вариантом (некоторые воспринимали как профессионализм )до реформы Минобразования. После неё нормативным признан словарь Резниченко, в котором дОговор признан равноправным вариантом и не считается ошибкой. Правда, это не означает, что все теперь должны говорить "дОговор". http://www.234555.ru/news/2009-09-09-177   Минобрнауки уже выступило с разъяснениями: "Новый перечень словарей русского языка рекомендован для использования чиновникам в работе и не вводит новые правила русского языка. В дальнейшем перечень может быть расширен до 30, возможно, до 50 словарей". Это рекомендации, а не закон. Так что выбор за вами: говорить так, как говорили культурные люди  на протяжении 20 века, или демократично, как та часть народа, которая пользуется разговорной речью как нормой.

http://www.rus-obr.ru/days/3979

Answer (score 1):

Немного об истории вопроса. Окончание Ы/И является основным для сущ. м.р., но они могут иметь и вариантное окончание А/Я, характерное для сущ. ср.р. Если вариантное окончание является единственным, то мы это просто не замечаем (снег - снега, берег - берега). Проблемы возникают в том случае, если в речи встречаются оба варианта. При этом важна акцентная характеристика слова. Если ударение в начальной форме падает на последний слог, то используется СТРОГО окончание Ы/И: договОр - договОры, инженЕр - инженЕры (грубо неправильно: инженерА).

В то же время для слова "договОр" словарь допускает вариант "дОговор", который определяется как РАЗГОВОРНЫЙ, тогда мы имеем дОговор - договорА, договорОв. В этом случае слово вписывается в ряд других слов с нейтральным окончанием Ы/И и разговорным окончанием А/Я: трАктор - трАкторы и тракторА, джЕмперы - джемперА, инспЕкторы - инспекторА, тОкари - токарЯ, хотя бывают исключения: профессорА, директорА, докторА, шулерА - только окончание А.

Answer (score -2):

Все свою жизнь я знала, что правильно говорить договОр. Когда слышу, что говорят дОговор, у меня начинается психоз. Как можно так коверкать русский язык?

Comment: Мы не занимаемся здесь психозами и эмоциональными вопросами "можно или нельзя". Достаточно указать источник правильного варианта или правило на него.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?